# Condition for Boolean field for in Qweb Report - Odoo11

Tags: odoo-11, qweb

Here is a Boolean field(collar2).
if Boolean is selected, the second field(collarmodel2) should be appear in Qweb report.

```
<t t-foreach="doc.modellines" t-as="line">

<span t-if="line.collar2=='True'">
<t t-esc="line.collarmodel2" />
</span>
</t>
```

Please help to correct it

Answer (score 0):

You should call the boolean value as a bool. You have given your condition value as a string ('True') not as boolean value.

```
<span t-if="line.collar2">
    <t t-esc="line.collarmodel2" />
</span>
```